# AutoNumeric - removes received values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autonumeric.js

I use autoNumeric. Data that is added to the `input` is cleared when you hover the `input` element. Why are the values ​​cleared? How to fix it? [Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyT0K.gif)

```js
$('#thermForwardStream').focusout(function () {
            var thermForwardStream = $('#thermForwardStream').val();
            var thermBackStream = $('#thermBackStream').val();
            if (thermBackStream == "70" ) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { 'thermForwardStream': thermForwardStream, 'thermBackStream': thermBackStream },
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetDataAnnexY", "ThermLosses")',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#tempHeatExchangerOne').val(data.thermForwardStream);
                $('#tempHeatExchangerTwo').val(data.thermBackStream);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

const autoNumericOptions = {
allowDecimalPadding: "floats",
            decimalCharacter: ",",
            digitGroupSeparator: "",
            emptyInputBehavior: "zero"
};

new AutoNumeric('#thermForwardStream', autoNumericOptions);
new AutoNumeric('#thermBackStream', autoNumericOptions);
new AutoNumeric('#tempHeatExchangerOne', autoNumericOptions);
new AutoNumeric('#tempHeatExchangerTwo', autoNumericOptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/autonumeric@4.1.0"></script>



<input class="form-control double" type="text" value="0" id="thermForwardStream" name="ThermForwardStream" required />

<input class="form-control double" type="text" value="70" id="thermBackStream" name="ThermBackStream" required />

<input class="form-control double" type="text" id="tempHeatExchangerOne" name="TempHeatExchangerOne" required />

<input class="form-control double" type="text" id="tempHeatExchangerTwo" name="TempHeatExchangerTwo" required />
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Need to add property `watchExternalChanges`.

> Defines if the AutoNumeric element should watch external changes made
>   without using .set()

```
 const autoNumericOptions = {
        allowDecimalPadding: "floats",
        decimalCharacter: ",",
        digitGroupSeparator: "",
        emptyInputBehavior: "zero",
        watchExternalChanges: true //!!!
    };
```